# Devolver cadena hash por numero

Tags: java, hash

he construido un programita hash que al pasarle una cadena me devuelve un numero codificado , ahora me gustaria una función que hiciera lo contrario de la misma formula que lo hicimos al codificar es decir que le pasemos un numero y muestre su cadena correspondiente es decir lo contrario, no se muy bien como empezar el metodo dejo lo que tengo planteado.

Comment: Como todo hash, el problema de volver es que hay varios caminos posibles y no hay garantía de que puedas usar los dos métodos y vuelvas a la cadena original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simple.

Fíjate que la clave la estás construyendo a base de multiplicar y sumar. Por lo tanto, para deshacer la clave tendrás que ir dividiendo entre 73 y el residuo que te quede será el índice del carácter del alfabeto.

Obviamente, haciéndolo así tendrás los carácteres de la cadena original en orden inverso, pero eso ya es una trivialidad.

Edito para añadir una implementación muy simple y rápida. Como te he dicho en los comentarios, has de preocuparte de girar el resultado para que la cadena sea legible. Ahí tienes el código adaptado a usar BigInteger y no tener problemas de fuera de rango.

```
public String hash2(BigInteger lo) {
    BigInteger mod = lo.mod(multiplicador);
    lo = lo.divide(multiplicador);
    String res = alfabeto.charAt(mod.intValue()) + "";

    while (lo.compareTo(tres) > 0) {
        mod = lo.mod(multiplicador);
        lo = lo.divide(multiplicador);
        res += alfabeto.charAt(mod.intValue());
    }

    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashPrueba hp = new HashPrueba();
    //hp.hash2(405611771492327055239928692427624877908760706915042668827730030781521901952046793);
    System.out.println(hp.hash2(hp.hash("javaguay")));

}
```

Comment: Buenas , muchas gracias estoy intentando hacer eso que me comentas pero no consigo sacarlo el parametro que sería el numero a convertir tengo que divirlo entre 73 tantas veces como sea la cadena? pero claro no se que cadena estoy llegando a una inconcluencia . Si me podrías poner un ejemplo se lo agradecira

Comment: Exacto. Has de ir dividiendo el número que recibes como parámetro entre 73 hasta que el resultado de la división sea 3 (porque la clave empiezas construyéndola multiplicando 3*73 y sumándole algo). El otro detalle a tener en cuenta es que el parámetro puede ser un número muy grande por lo que trabajar con Integer o Long queda completamente descartado.

Comment: Buenas si he modificado mi código pero cuando le paso cualquier numero es decir en vez de pasarle hash , me salta el error de que se salta de rango. Aunque le pase un número mas pequeño

Comment: ¿Lo has probado con el código que he puesto? Ese funciona perfectamente (el resultado será "yaugavaj"). ¿Y qué es lo que se sale de rango, el valor que estás pasando o el acceso a la posición del diccionario?

Comment: Claro si sale perfecto sale "yaugavaj" pero cuando el valor  es diferente o le paso un long al hash2 ya salta esto Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 50
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at hashprueba.HashPrueba.hash2(HashPrueba.java:34)
 at hashprueba.HashPrueba.main(HashPrueba.java:52)

Comment: Te da ese error porque no estás usando BigInteger y, por tanto, los resultados de las divisiones no son correctos e intentas acceder a posiciones del diccionario que no son válidas. Has de reemplazar todo uso de Long por BigInteger. Ahora edito mi respuesta y cambio el método