# Quiero generar un long de un String y que ese long sea unico y si quiero generarlo de nuevo con el mismo String me de el mismo numero. En java

Tags: java, algoritmos

Tengo una app que me llega un String, necesito generar un long, pero no puedo usar algo aleatoreo, necesito que para el mismo String me del el mismo long siempre, poque el String me llega varias veces en el proceso.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! o sea, queres generar un hash. y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Devolver cadena hash por numero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163107/devolver-cadena-hash-por-numero)